# Solve $z^5 - iz^3+iz^2+1 =0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve for $z$:
$$z^5 - iz^3+iz^2+1 =0$$
I've ruled out the approach with euler's representation, de moivre's way led me to $\cos4\phi + \sin3\phi-\sin2\phi +1 = 0$ (with the assumption that the length of $z$ is $1$, which I derived from the fact that $i$ is one of the solutions, which shows trivially through horner's algorithm). Substituting $z$ with $a+ bi$ got me some very ugly numerical solutions for $a$, and as previously mentioned, $i$ is a solution that leads to the equation $$z^4+iz^3+(-1-i)z^2+z+i=0$$I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^5 - iz^3+iz^2+1 =z^3(z^2-i)+i(z^2-i)=(z^3+i)(z^2-i)$$

You should be able to solve it now.

Comment: wow, thanks, may I ask how you figured this out, was there a methodical approach involved or just mathematical intuition?

Comment: @uroskozole I simply guess that this factorisation may work. You may say it is intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$z^3(z^2-i)+i(z^2-i)=?$$